# Limit integer and decimal parts length in flex

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, token, flex-lexer, lex

Is there a way I can extract the number of digits before and after the '.' in a float in Flex?
I want to limit the number of digits in the integer part to 4, and of the decimal part to 8. So that the total of the characters including '.' will be up to 13.

this is what I did:

I get errors only if the float is more than 13 in length. But when it has more than 4 characters in integer part or more than 8 characters in decimal part, I don't get any error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes I mean float, sorry, I didn't translate it from French to English.

Comment: No, I didn't have such warnings.

Comment: Please read the first few paragraphs of [this section of the Flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html#Matching), which describes how flex scanners proceed through the file.

Comment: I wouldn't do this in the lexer. I was taught many years ago by Frank de Remer that the lexer should not concern itself with values or conversions. I would make it a semantic error much later on. In any case your rule is wrong. There is no reason for an overall limit of 13 at all. There is a limit on the number of decimal places *before* the decimal point, but after it you can have as many as you like, and how much (if any) of the specified precision is lost depends on the actual value.

Comment: I read the document you sent, thank you, but I'm looking for a function or a way to extract some characters from a token in order to count them.

Comment: You can count the characters either by counting them (they're in `yytext`), or by scanning the number as two separate tokens and combining them afterwards. What you can't do is match part of a token with one rule while you match the whole token with another rule.

Comment: @user207421 It doesn't even work for the integer part. I throught it should be a lexical error not a semantic one.

Comment: I'm using: flex lexical.l       bison -d syntaxique.y        gcc lex.yy.c syntaxique.tab.c -lfl -ly -o compiler

Comment: Ryma: "Lexical errors" are actually a bit of a pain, although there certainly are such things. You really don't want to split error handling between the parser and the lexer; producing good error messages is difficult enough without having to do it twice. So there's a lot to be said for leaving error detection to the parser, as @user207421 suggests. But there are errors which must be detected in the scanner (unterminated string literals, for example), so sometimes it's convenient to pass an error indication on to the parser by using a special token, as I do in the sample code in my answer.

Comment: Also, you need to think through whether a particular input is really an error (as @user207421 also suggests). Is it really necessary to limit floating point decimal parts to 8 digits? Why? Every error condition has a cost: it must be detected, reported, and then replaced with something else so that the parse can continue. You really don't want to go to all that work just to avoid something without impact.

Answer (score 1):

In (f)lex, macros (`{...}`) are just macros; they're replaced with their definition (normally surrounded by parentheses to avoid the usual problem with macro expansion). So you can't use `{IntPart}` and `{DecPart}` to perform actions on subsequences in the `{float}` pattern. Either `{float}` (that is, the macro expansion of that macro) matches, or one of the other two patterns match.

That's going to have confusing results because your `{IntPart}` pattern does not match what you want it to. You want it to match either a 0 or an integer which doesn't start with 0. That would be `[1-9][0-9]*|0`. The pattern, `([1-9][0-9])*|0` matches 0 or integers of even length (and then, only if the digits in odd positions are not 0). Other integers will be matched by the `{DecPart}` pattern, which is also active (because all rules are always active, unless you use scanner states).

Since some integers match one of those patterns and other integers match the other one, it's quite possible that the wrong length test will be applied. The integer `12345`, for example, will match the `{DecPart}` pattern and will be compared with the length 8, so it won't trigger an error message. So the first thing you should do is to try to fix your patterns so that they actually match what you want them to, remembering that you need to match the entire token.

You could, of course, send off partial tokens, thereby complicating the grammar somewhat. One way to do that would be to use something like this:

```
0|[1-9][0-9]*      { if (yyleng <= 4) return INT_PART;
                     fprintf(stderr, "%s: Integer part too long\n", yytext);
                     return BAD_TOKEN;
                   }
"."[0-9]+          { if (yyleng <= 9) return DEC_PART;
                     fprintf(stderr, "%s: Decimal part too long\n", yytext);
                     return BAD_TOKEN;
                   }
```

but then your parser will have to stick the two things together. And the parser doesn't actually know whether there was whitespace between the two parts, so that's going to need some more work. [Note 1]

Personally, I'd just do the match and later on check to make sure that neither part is too long. Or convert the whole thing to a floating point number and compare it with 10000, which is undoubtedly the simplest option.

---

#### Notes:

1. You could use a lexer state --a "start condition"-- to only allow the decimal part rule immediately after an integer part has been recognised. And you could even condition that all on the existence of the `.`. So technically, you could do what you want. But it's a lot of work for little purpose, and the consequence will be code which is much harder to maintain.

Comment: There is a subtlety here. In *lex(1),* a macro is replaced by its definition. In *flex(1)* it is replaced by its definition surrounded by parentheses. Vern Paxson fixed this at my request in about 1988, as I stated 'in my opinion this is a bug in *lex(1)*'.

Comment: @user207421: sure, I mention that at the beginning of the answer. It's certainly less problematic than C macros, although there are still quirks. Regardless, they are just macros. They do not add any structure to the recognised tokens, as many users (including, I guess, this one) seem to believe.

Comment: Well I am clarifying what you wrote, which doesn't state which action is taken by which implementation.